# Extract specific text from pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, text, coordinates, locate

How to extract specific text from a pdf using python?

ex: Pdf contain ( Name: Python , Color: Blue ). In that case I want to extract whatever text that comes after "Name:" and not to extract any text after the "," between "Python" and "Color".

Any help is appreciated.

```py
import PyPDF2 

pdf = open("C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\test.pdf)

reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf)

page = reader.pages[0]

print(page.extract_text())
```

This extracts the whole pdf.

Comment: why not extracting all the text and then your problem will just be: How to extract specific tokens and values from text in python? If the text from the pdf has delimiters it shouldn't be difficult to parse it and extract the desired elements. Please can you post an example of the text that you extract from the pdf and the part of this text that you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

If your library returns a string, you can use regex to find your desired output:

```
import re

text = "Name: Python , Color: Blue"
span = re.match("Name:.*,", text).span()
# Add 5 to starting position to remove "Name:"
print(text[span[0]+5:span[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the PyMuPDF package.

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
doc=fitz.open("test.pdf")
page = doc[0]

blocks = page.get_text("blocks")  # extract text separated by paragraphs

# a block is a tuple starting with 4 floats followed by lines in paragraph
for b in blocks:
    lines = b[4].splitlines()  # lines in the paragraph
    for line in lines:  # look for lines having 'Name:' and 'Color:'
        p1 = line.find("Name:")
        if p1 < 0:
            continue
        p2 = line.fine("Color:", p1)
        if p2 < 0:
            continue
        text = line[p1+5:p2]  # all text in between
        p3 = text.find(",")  # find any comma
        if p3 >= 0:  # there, shorten text accordingly
            text = text[:p3]
        # finished
```